# How can a TPL task send intermediate results to the parent thread?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am working with TPL and need to have a long running TPL task send results to the parent UI thread without terminating. I have tried several approaches and have been googling quite a bit. Does anyone know how to make this happen with TPL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass in a delegate to call with periodic results, and a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) which the task could use to invoke the callback on the correct thread. That's basically the way that `BackgroundWorker` does it (and the way that the async feature of C# 5 will "know" where to call you back) - it captures [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) on the calling thread, then calls [`Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) (IIRC) to post a message to the right context. You then just need to wrap the original callback in a [`SendOrPostCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback.aspx) which executes it when it's got to the right thread.

EDIT: Sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        Label label = new Label();
        form.Controls.Add(label);
        form.Load += delegate { HandleLoaded(label); };
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    static void HandleLoaded(Label label)
    {
        Action<string> callback = text => label.Text = text;
        StartTask(callback);
    }

    static void StartTask(Action<string> callback)
    {
        SendOrPostCallback postCallback = obj => callback((string) obj);
        SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string text = i.ToString();
                context.Post(postCallback, text);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kaizen: Done. Note how the `StartTask` method knows *nothing* about the fact that it's a Windows Forms app - the same code would work in a WPF app.

Comment: I ran into a little problem trying to make this work from a unit test. First the current SynchronizationContext was null, then when I created one I still was unable to callback on the parent's thread. Instead the callback went to a new thread. Do you know how to respond back on the parent's thread?

Comment: @Kaizen: That depends on the parent thread. I suspect that in a unit test, you're working on a thread pool thread already, so there's nothing like the UI event pump.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application you are using there might be different approaches.

- WinForms: [*Control.Invoke*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)
- WPF/Silverlight/WP7 and derivates: [*Dispatcher.Invoke*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)
- Some other type of application: define what *UI thread* means first?